# Storyboard not working in portrait mode iOS Swift Xcode 6

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xcode6

I am developing an iOS application which is not showing up in portrait mode in simulator but working well in landscape mode. Problem is not solved even after setting the ViewController's orientation to portrait mode. Did anyone face this problem?

Regards,
Chanikya

Comment: What do you mean by working in the landscape mode but not in the portrait mode? Can you describe more specific?

Comment: If you ran the app, does it show in landscape mode? If so is the view controller in landscape mode in your storyboard? have you modified code which alters the orientation of the view controller?

Normally the app will intrinsically fall back to portrait mode, so something must have been changed to make your project behave in such a manner.

Comment: When i run the app, simulator opens up in portrait mode with blank white screen. But when i rotate the device to landscape mode, it is working. I didn't modify the code to alter the orientation of the view controller.